# How to import export route in node express?

Tags: node.js, rest, express

This is my directory structure

```
- server.js
- /api
  - indexRoute.js
  - /routes
    - authenticateRoute.js
    - userMgtRoute.js
```

I have create `/api/routes` directory >> Here I have kept all the routes. One level up of this directory I have created `indexROute.js` which imports all the routes. Now I want to import `indexRoute.js` to my `server.js`

> this is my **server.js** file

```
var express = require('express'), app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

var indexRoute = require('./api/indexRoute.js');
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    console.log('START: A new req found');
    next();
});
app.listen(PORT);
console.log('Server started on: ' + PORT);
```

> this is my /api/indexRoute.js

```
var userProfileRoute = require('./routes/userProfileRoute.js');
var dashboardRoute = require('./routes/dashboardRoute.js');

app.use('/userprofile', userProfileRoute);
app.use('/userprofile/:id', userProfileRoute);

app.use('/dashboard', dashboardRoute);
app.use('/dashboard/:userid', dashboardRoute);
```

> under `/route` directory I have written all the routes. I have imported all the routes to `indexRoute.js`. Am I doing it correctly? How do i import all routes to  `indexRoute.js` and further `indexRoute.js` to `server.js`.